# Which is the most stable version of Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop

I've tried installing Ubuntu 11.10, uninstalling and reinstalling 11.04 etc. After day 1, though, some bug or the other shows up and then I spend the rest of my time looking up fixes on the Internet. I don't like criticizing Ubuntu a lot because I don't pay a penny for the awesome OS. What is the most stable version of Ubuntu for Notebook PCs?

Comment: The most stable version of an operating system typically is the latest one? I'd much rather try to fix any bugs you may experience along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest versions marked as "stable" are always available from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

But, personally I prefer [Debian](http://www.debian.org/distrib/) over Ubuntu. Ubuntu is a Debian-based OS, but for me as a power user doesn't add that much useful features that I'm missing in Debian itself.

Comment: Is Debian really more stable than Ubuntu from your experience?

Comment: @slhck: not only do I find it more stable, but it also gets you closer to the original source and Debian also maintains their own software repositories used by aptitude/apt-get very effectively. The Debian test repos are often tested more extensively before anything is released into the stable repos.

Comment: Which also means that Debian software versions are rather ancient, doesn't it?

Comment: @DanielBeck Sometimes it does. But if having the latest version is mission-critical for you(r day to day work), you're best off by compiling the latest versions yourself to your own wishes and needs anyway, rather then using unfully tested packages.

Comment: Or add the testing/unstable repos to your `sources.list`. I use Debian configured as a rolling testing release.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the LTS release should be more stable. There are less new features etc. in those releases. The current LTS release is 10.04 and the next will be 12.04.

According to the Ubuntu download page:

> Our long-term support (LTS) releases are supported for three years on the desktop. Perfect for organisations that need more stability for larger deployments.