# Whats a stable version of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Ubuntu onto my laptop the other day for a change of pace but it keeps on crashing and stalling. I will freeze for a while or just stop completely and i cannot do anything on it. I have version 14.04 LTS. What is a stable version?

Comment: 14.04 LTS is a stable version. Sounds like a hardware incompatibility or fault somewhere. Did you have any problems with Windows, which I assume you had previously?

Comment: There was no issues with windows at all on my laptop. it has 4 gb of ram, an intel core 13 4010u @1.70GHz, 500GB hhd, 64 bit system

Comment: It certainly sounds like it *should* work, but it's impossible for us to say where the problem is. Could be an incompatibility with any device on your machine. Without logs and knowing the exact specifications, it'll be impossible to say (I don't use Linux on a daily basis so I can't say where to begin with this I'm afraid). Maybe look up if anyone else has had problems with Ubuntu and your laptop model.

Comment: +1 for @Jonno Also, I was having similar issues recently after installing 14.04 LTS but after a day or two and many `apt-get` it seems to be working just fine

Comment: Assuming you verified the hash to ensure that you installed a good copy of the iso, it sounds like an incompatibility, driver problem, or something similar.  The OS is a pretty stable product.  That said, I have occasionally run into problems with drivers and various bugs with Ubuntu.  One quick thing to try is to install Mint.  It's based on Ubuntu LTS, but they add their own layer of testing, drivers, and refinement.  Mint tends to be less problem prone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the most stable version of Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/374108/which-is-the-most-stable-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: I tried using Mint but it lags after awhile of my laptop being on. it is impossible to use when it lags otherwise its good

Answer (score 2):

The first time I installed Ubuntu, it was on a computer that was having problems running Windows, and a similar thing happened. The computer died a few days later. I didn't give up and installed Ubuntu on a different computer, and it ran perfectly. In answer to your question, Ubuntu 14.04 is a Long Term Support release and it's generally considered to be a stable version of Ubuntu, as all LTS releases of Ubuntu are.

To check if your computer's hardware is compatible with Ubuntu, run Ubuntu from a live DVD/USB without installing it on your hard drive and/or see [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, any Ubuntu release that doesn't have "beta", "alpha", or "RC" word in their name is a stable version. Your version is a stable version, and I assume you were confused by the "LTS" word. It stands for "Long Term Support", which basically means the developers are keep fixing problems for this version for a longer time. Check out [this graph](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) for life cycles of Ubuntu releases.

Regarding your crash and stalling problems, I feel the same as some comments have pointed out, that there's a hardware incompatibility. I run into similar problems on one of my many laptops, and I felt there's nothing I can do to fix but returning back to Windows.

Comment: I did the same a few days ago, i gave up on it